# Caught in Restangular promises

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I've got this code:

```
var me = Restangular.one('object', 1).get({params:params});

me.then(function (data) {

    $scope.me = data;
    $scope.loadsubobject();
});


$scope.loadsubobject = function () {

    $scope.me.getList("subobject")
    .then(function(subobject) {
    //the code never gets here
            console.log('loaded subobjects', subobjects);
            $scope.subobjects = $scope.subobjects.concat(subobject.results);

            if (data.next){
                $scope.next = data.next;
            }
      },function(response){
       console.log('Error with response:', response.status)
        });
```

when I try to debug the code It seems that after calling the `$scope.me.getList("subobject")`It returns to the first `then`and never getting to the second then, the one that actually process the subobjects I need.

Any clue out of call back hell?

I verified that the server does return the correct answer
How can I fix that? be glad for help with this

Comment: I'm not super familiar with restangular, but I'm pretty sure when you say `$scope.me = data` in the `me.then()` handler, you're not going to have a `getList` function on `me`.

Comment: Thought so too. but I do get the function.

Comment: I guess Restangular wraps the result, that's pretty cool. So loadsubject runs, but the "then" success never fires, and the error handler never fires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turned out to be a completely different issue, the json returned wasn't "flat", so I need to use a `responseExtractor` [as explained here](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#setresponseinterceptor-or-setresponseextractor-its-an-alias)